# Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'NSDictionary *' is disallowed with ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm getting the error "Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'NSDictionary *' is disallowed with ARC" when I use NSFileManager - attributesOfItemAtPath.

I guess some error occurred while I'm try to knowing size of file.
Is there any method to solving this problem?

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *fName = @"testfile";
        NSFileManager *fm;
        NSDictionary *attr;


        fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];


        if([fm fileExistsAtPath:fName]==NO){
            NSLog(@"File doesnt exist!");
            return 1;
        }


        if([fm copyItemAtPath:fName toPath:@"newfile" error:nil]==0){
            NSLog(@"Files copy Failed!");
            return 2;
        }


        if([fm contentsEqualAtPath:@"newfile" andPath:@"newfile2"] == NO){
            NSLog(@"File arent equal");
            return 3;
        }


        if([fm moveItemAtPath:@"newfile" toPath:@"newfile2" error:nil] == NO){
            NSLog(@"file rename failed");
            return 4;
        }

        //Here
        if((attr = [fm attributesOfItemAtPath:@"newfile2" error:nil] == NO)){

            return 5;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Other methods you're using: `moveItemAtPath`, `contentsEqualAtPath`, `copyItemAtPath`, `fileExistsAtPath` - they all return a `BOOL`. But `attributesOfItemAtPath` returns `NSDictionary` and you can't compare `NSDictionary` to `BOOL` (`NO`)

try instead

```
((attr = [fm attributesOfItemAtPath:@"newfile2" error:nil]) == nil)
```

Comment: Thank you. it just simple syntax error.
im changing my code your suggestion and
also change code from (attr= ~~) to ((attr = ~~)==nil).

Comment: I do not believe, that this works, because `==` binds stronger than `=`, IIRC.

Comment: True, `==` has higher precedence than `=`

Answer (score 0):

You compare a reference to an instance of a dictionary with the integral type `NO`, what is an integer. Likely you want to check against `nil`. Moreover you should use parenthesis on the left side, otherwise the compiler tries to assing the result of `[…]==NO` to attribute:

```
if( (attr = [fm attributesOfItemAtPath:@"newfile2" error:nil]) == nil)
```